# Dreamweaver regex number finder

Tags: regex, algorithm, dreamweaver

I have several links and they are followed by a number. The numbers so far are 5000 or 2048. I want to find the rest of the numbers that aren't 5000 or 2048.

The links looks like this:

```
mylink:5000
mylink:2048
```

There are 3213 instances of those two numbers in my files. But when I take the number out and just have mylink: there are 3219 instances. So there are 6 links that have a different number and I'd like to find them without having to look through each individual file.

It's my understanding that it's possible to do this with a regex algorithm, but I'm very new to this so I could use some help.
Thanks

Comment: Use something like `\b(?!(5000|2048)\b)\d+`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?!(5000|2048)\b)\d+
```

The pattern will match any 1 or more digit  sequences as *whole words* that are not `5000` or `2048`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MGglfy/2).

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!(5000|2048)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the word boundary is followed with `5000` or `2048` and a trailing word boundary
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits